# Can Visual Studio tell me when others make changes in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

I use VS 2013 premium with TFS. I can easily see stuff that I have changed (with Pending Changes). However, how can I see all the stuff that other people have changed in this solution? I know that I can just do "Get Latest Recursive" on the solution, and this will give me all the updates. However, I want to **see a list of updates to this solution,** but **without actually getting the updates**.  Is that possible?

**Edit:** Ideally I'd like to have a real-time indicator, like a red light comes on whenever someone else checks in anything to the solution. And then I can click it to see what the changes are.

Comment: Looks like I could open a command window and type "tf get * /recursive /preview" to see what updates I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Team Explorer --> Settings --> Project Alerts you should be able to setup an alert that will email you when "Anything is checked in" but I've never tried it.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I prefer something that will tell me whether my current  files are up to date or not.